# Prove that a linear equation in two variables has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I guess just saying that 'for every value of x there is another value for y' is not enough. Is there any rigorous proof of this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equation $ax + by = c$.

Now we know that there is a number $d = lcm(a, b)$.

Let $ad_1 = d \text{ and } bd_2 = d$. So, $ad_1 - bd_2 = 0$. Note that neither $d_1$ nor $d_2$ is $0$.

$$ax + by + ad_1 - bd_2 = c$$
$$a(x+d_1) + b(y- d_2) = c$$

Thus, for every solution of this linear diophantine equation of two variables, there exists another unique solution. Hence, there is an infinite number of solutions to this equation.

Answer (score 1):

An equation of the type $ax+by=0$ where both $a,b \neq 0$ has solutions $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ of the type $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ -ax/b \end{pmatrix}$ that varies for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ax+by=c$ be the equation.
Let $f:F\to F$ by $x\mapsto(x,y)$, where $y=\frac{c-ax}b$. Then, $f$ is an isomorphism. As $F$ is infinite, there are infinitely many solutions.

Note: $F$ is the field you are working on. It always helps to specify it.